# Variable arity scheme

Tags: variables, scheme, arity

```
(define test (lambda args 
  (if (= (length args) 1) (display (car args))
      (begin (display (car args))
      (test (cdr args))))))
```

I was looking for it on the net and didnt find the answer, I was able to get a variable number of arguments to my func, but how do i pass them not as a single list to the next iteration?

To be more clearer, if i call :

```
(test (list 1 1) (list 2 2) (list 3 3))
```

i was exepcting to get :

```
(1 1) (2 2) (3 3)
```

but i get :

```
(1 1) ((2 2) (3 3))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` will be a list of the arguments passed to `test`. The first time you pass it three lists, so `args` will be a list of those three lists. Recursively you pass it `(cdr args)`, which is a list of the last two lists, so now `args` is a list containing the list that has the last two lists. That is, `args` is `(((2 2) (3 3)))` where you want `((2 2) (3 3))`. You can fix it by [applying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply#Common_Lisp_and_Scheme) the `test` function to the list:

```
(apply test (cdr args))
```

Which, if `(cdr args)` is `((2 2) (3 3))`, is the same as doing:

```
(test (2 2) (3 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (test . args)
  (if (= (length args) 1)
    (display (car args))
    (begin
      (display (car args))
      (apply test (cdr args)))))
```

Comment: what does the dot mean? and what does apply do?

Comment: The dot means that the next parameter will be given a list that holds all of the remaining arguments to the function.  "apply" is used to break up a list into individual arguments to a function; (apply + '(1 3 5 7)) is equivalent to (+ 1 3 5 7); "apply" is also found in Lisp.  Both are standard, basic Scheme.